# Songs refuse to transfer to iPad

Tags: itunes, ios, data-synchronization, music, file-transfer

I'm copying an album of non-DRM songs from iTunes (where they all play just fine) to an iPad. Three of the songs on the album were downloaded through the Bandcamp purchase interface (let's call it method A), and they transfer fine, but the rest were downloaded directly as .mp3 files (method B), and do not transfer. Rather, they ostensibly do: the song appears in iTunes and in Music.app, but does not play in either and appears greyed out in iTunes with a grey sync icon next to it.

There are several other albums also gotten by method B, which all transfer completely fine. What in the world is going on, and how can I fix it?

I am running Mac OS 10.7.3, iOS 5.0.1, iTunes 10.5.3 (3), and am using an iPad "1". I've already tried deleting them from the iPad and re-copying, but it still only copies the three "A" songs.

Comment: Please be more specific about the different methods.

Comment: Edited. A: Bandcamp purchase interface, B: direct .mp3 file downloads via the Internet.

Comment: It's possible that while the songs may play on the computer, they may be corrupt in some way. As a test, try converting the existing B MP3s to MP3 format within iTunes, and see if the converted ones work.

Comment: What does iTunes say about the mp3 format against these songs?  Such as bitrate etc

Comment: @StuWilson OK, here's everything that could possibly be relevant: **Method A files:** AAC, 170 kbps, stereo, low complexity. **Method B files:** MPEG, 128 kbps, MPEG-1 layer 3 formatting, joint stereo. I don't see how the differences between A and B would have an effect, though, as all the B files (including the few-hundred successful ones) are the same in terms of these specs.

Comment: @RandolphWest How can I do that? The only thing I can find converts them to AAC... Also, my earlier comment was incorrect: the A files are AACs, and the B files are MPEGs.